# Run a series of commands on a number of files

Tags: bash, scripting, bioinformatics

I have the following files:

```
FC_014_6361.bam
FC_014_6462.bam
FC_014_6183.bam
```

Presently I run the following commands separately on each file. For example for `FC_014_6361.bam` the commands are:

```
$ bedtools intersect -abam FC_014_6361.bam -b CLIA-bed-for-DRAGEN_1.bed > FC_014_6361Inter.bam

$ samtools sort FC_014_6361Inter.bam > FC_014_6361InterSort.bam

$ samtools depth -a FC_014_6361InterSort.bam -b CLIA-bed-for-DRAGEN_1.bed > FC_014_6361InterSortDepth.txt

$ awk '$3<20' FC_014_6361InterSortDepth.txt > 6361_20.txt
```

Doing this for many files of this type is tedious. Could someone help with a script that would automate this and explain it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each source file name, you modify it slightly and save the result in a file named after the original. Using this information we can construct a loop.

Put the following into a file, for example `doit`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
for bamsrc in "$@"               # For each item on the command line
do
    prefix="${bamsrc%.bam}"      # Strip off trailing .bam
    result="${prefix##*_}"       # Strip off leading *_
    echo "Processing '$bamsrc' into intermediate bam files and ${result}_20.txt"

    # Perform the processing
    bedtools intersect -abam "$bamsrc" -b CLIA-bed-for-DRAGEN_1.bed > "${prefix}Inter.bam"
    samtools sort "${prefix}Inter.bam" >"${prefix}InterSort.bam"
    samtools depth -a "${prefix}InterSort.bam" -b CLIA-bed-for-DRAGEN_1.bed > "${prefix}InterSortDepth.txt"
    awk '$3<20' "${prefix}InterSortDepth.txt" > "${result}_20.txt"
done
```

Make the script file executable

```
chmod a+x doit
```

Then run it with the source filenames as a space separated list

```
./doit FC_014_6361.bam FC_014_6462.bam FC_014_6183.bam
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to start with. Haven't tested it but it might help you to create your solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *.bam;do
    number=$( echo $filename | grep -o '[0-9]\+' )
    bedtools intersect -abam $filename -b CLIA-bed-for-DRAGEN_1.bed > "$filename"Inter.bam
    samtools sort "$filename"Inter.bam > "$filename"InterSort.bam
    samtools depth -a "$filename"InterSort.bam -b CLIA-bed-for-DRAGEN_1.bed > "$filename"InterSortDepth.txt
    awk '$3<20' "$filename"InterSortDepth.txt > "$number"_20.txt
done
```

Comment: check if the regex [0-9]\+ works for your filenames to extract the number used in last command

Comment: roaima, my bad. Edited!